# First Data Telecheck (ICA) integration

Tags: api, firstdata, linkpoint

I am working on integration Firstdata telecheck to my shopping cart. I have a staging account for Credit card processing and I have use the same for telecheck processing.

Response I am getting is:

**SGS-020019: Not authorized to do this type of transaction.**

I guess telecheck is not enable in my account. I tried to connect with Firstdata support but did not get much help as it is a staging/demo account.

Any help to work around it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Firstdata do not provides sandbox environment for Telecheck. We need to get it enabled on production environment and test it their.